# Is it possible to plug a thumbdrive / portable harddisk that have multiple partitions to a tablet

Tags: usb-host-mode, partitions

Is it possible to plug a thumbdrive / portable harddisk that have multiple partitions to a tablet (any generic tablet or tablets in general)

or there is a need to use a Apps to perform such actions?